# Install just one package globally on Julia

Tags: server, installation, julia

I have a fresh Julia instalation on a machine that I want to use as a number-crunching server for various persons on a lab. There seems to be this nice package called jupyterhub wich makes the Jupyter Notebook interface avaible to various clients simultaneusly. A web page which I am unable to find again began suggesting something like "first install IJulia globally, then install JupyterHub..."

I cannot seem to find a nice way to install ONE package globally.

Comment: from jupyterhub's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-demo-images/blob/master/Dockerfile#L90) line 91, nothing special,  just run `julia -e 'Pkg.add("IJulia")`

Comment: No, that doesn't work. It installs it just for the user who issued the command. I want **one** IJulia instalation and not that every user has to do it for itself. Julia is allready globally installed, that was easy. But I do not find a way to do it for just one package, specially this one that has to interact with jupyter /jupyterhub.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

In Julia-v0.7+, we need to use `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` instead of `JULIA_PKGDIR` and the `LOAD_PATH` looks something like this:

```
julia> LOAD_PATH
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 Base.CurrentEnv()                                                                                                                     
 Any[Base.NamedEnv("v0.7.0"), Base.NamedEnv("v0.7"), Base.NamedEnv("v0"), Base.NamedEnv("default"), Base.NamedEnv("v0.7", create=true)]
 "/Users/gnimuc/Codes/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7"
```

## Old Post

> "first install IJulia globally, then install JupyterHub..."

I don't know whether this is true or not, by following these steps below, you can install `IJulia` after you installed `Jupyterhub`.

### Install packages system-wide/globally for every user

this question has already been answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/9lQZJlLs99M) by Stefan Karpinski. so what we need is just use this method to install the `IJulia.jl` package.

> There's a Julia variable called LOAD_PATH that is arranged to point at two system directories under your julia installation. E.g.:

```
julia> LOAD_PATH
2-element Array{Union(ASCIIString,UTF8String),1}:
 "/opt/julia-0.3.3/usr/local/share/julia/site/v0.3"
 "/opt/julia-0.3.3/usr/share/julia/site/v0.3"
```

> If you install packages under either of those directories, then everyone using that Julia will see them. One way to do this is to run julia as a user who can write to those directories after doing `export JULIA_PKGDIR=/opt/julia-0.3.3/usr/share/julia/site` in the shell. That way Julia will use that as it's package directory and normal package commands will allow you to install packages for everyone....

### Make IJulia working with Jupyterhub

in order to make `IJulia` and `Jupyterhub` working with each other for all the users, you should copy the folder `your/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia/` to `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/`. I write down some of the steps that I used in my test [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Gnimuc/jupyterhub-docker-images/blob/master/Dockerfile). the code is ugly, but it works.

### Steps: (after you successfully installed Jupyterhub)

note that, you should do the following steps as root and I assume that your julia was globally installed at `/opt/julia_0.4.0/`.

1. make our global package directory and set up `JULIA_PKGDIR`:

   ```
   mkdir /opt/global-packages
   echo 'push!(LOAD_PATH, "/opt/global-packages/.julia/v0.4/")' >> /opt/julia_0.4.0/etc/julia/juliarc.jl
   export JULIA_PKGDIR=/opt/global-packages/.julia/
   ```
2. install "IJulia" using package manager:

   ```
   julia -e 'Pkg.init()'
   julia -e 'Pkg.add("IJulia")'
   ```
3. copy `kernelspec`s to `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/` which can be used by any new user added by `Jupyterhub`:

   ```
   jupyter kernelspec list
   cd /usr/local/share/ && mkdir -p jupyter/kernels/
   cp -r /home/your-user-name/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-0.4-your-julia-version /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/
   ```