# Can't install IJulia in a preexisting Jupyter

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've installed Jupyter in my server from Pypi (so, no conda). To install the Julia kernel I've entered the following commands in Julia console:

```
julia> ENV["JUPYTER"]="/usr/local/bin/jupyter"
julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

But the kernel doesn't appear in Jupyter.

Julia version is 0.4.5 (from Ubuntu 16.04 repos).

Comment: Just checking, is jupyter in your `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`?

Comment: Also, have you tried `julia> using IJulia` and then `julia> notebook()` once?

Comment: Yes it is. When I use `julia> notebook()` I get this message: `Process(setenv('/usr/local/bin/jupyter notebook'; dir="/root"), ProcessExited(1))`

Comment: Another problem is that I'm doing this in a server running a JupyterHub instance. Users don't can't access the terminal to use Julia's console.

Comment: What is the output of `which jupyter`?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`

Comment: Do you have access to `/root`? You could also trying running `Pkg.build("IJulia")`. And what is the output of `jupyter --version`?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged as the root user. The output is `4.3.0`.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338701/install-just-one-package-globally-on-julia)? You'll have to substitute in your own paths. You could also try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chronitis/jupyter & sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install ijulia`, but I'm not sure if this will work.